# Layout issue in implementing popup window in CSS

Tags: css, target

Hello I have some issues with a code. I'm trying to do the following. When OPEN POPUP is clicked this will make popup visible and it will cover the whole screen. When X in content is clicked this will close the content and make it will make popup invisible again.

I have achieved this using `:target` pseudo-class.

You can see the demo here: https://codepen.io/loganlee/pen/Jjdjzom?editors=1100

[image]

I have two problems. First, OPEN POPUP link is visible on top of screen and it is not covered by `.popup`.  Even though I've done `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`.

```
.popup
{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(black, .8);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10rem 0;
}
```

Second, `.popup__content` is taller than `.popup` when height of screen is made really small. You can see both in the picture.

I think I've done something wrong with layout. Thanks.

Comment: fixed the first issue by adding top: 0 to .popup. this seems to have fixed the second issue as well..... any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add these style to your code.. for your two issues.

```css
.popup {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```